# Ratio of zero-pole in a lead compensator

Tags: transfer-function, compensation

I have a transfer function of a lead compensator designed for double integrator in the form
$$G(s)=\frac{2025}{s^2}\frac{s/39+1}{s/139+1}$$

The zero frequency is 39 rad/s and pole is 139 rad/s. I just did few simulation and found that when the pole frequency is around 100 fz, the overshoots are around 26%. Whereas for the above TF, overshoot is around 47%, with no advantages over rise time, settling time or BW. Any apparent advantages of this zero/pole ratio of a lead compensator?

Comment: \$\dfrac{2025}{s^2}\$ = `\$\dfrac{2025}{s^2}\$` for example.

Comment: recently found out that wolfram can do root locus, [it might help](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=root+locus+of+1000*%28s%2F39+%2B+1%29+%2F+%28s%5E2+*+%28s%2F139%2B1%29%29)  // as you can see, for that choice of compensator pole/zero there's a sweet spot for the gain before it turns vertical (thus mostly goes to oscillation)

Comment: for comparison, [here's one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=root+locus+of+1000*%28s%2F39+%2B+1%29+%2F+%28s%5E2+*+%28s%2F300%2B1%29%29) with higher compensator pole ... takes RL further to left (-100 ish) while keeping it closer to the real axis

Comment: What is the conclusion?

Comment: Yes I believe so. For example, using the root locus method, and arbitrarily keeping the same zero, I got 4250*(s/39 + 1) / (s^2 * (s/300+1)) . Bode plot and phase margin suggest faster rise, less overshoot. With the faster response, the overshoot could be ironed out using an additional low-pass on the input to the loop, trading some of the extra speed for the step response. (You can also experiment with moving the zero in the feedback path). All this assumes there are not "large signal" considerations (i.e. some rate or value saturating in the signal path)

Comment: i.e. the strategy of increasing zero frequency and gain will eventually run into some limitation

Comment: If I keep zero fixed and move the poles. I did not see any issue. BW remains same, rise time and overshoots are reduced. Yes beyond 20 times Fzero, BW reduces. Still I do not see any serious limitations. Not really getting the crux!!

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: I do not see the condition when the system will run into limitation. Could you explain that

Comment: if increased too much, higher gain and/or larger (i.e. faster) poles will eventually do some combination of the following : amplify noise more, will cause system to be limited by its *slew rate*, will saturate for even small input steps. Saturation recovery can also cause oscillation in some cases.